# printing $_GET values in another PHP page

Tags: php

I have the following. My issue is when the 'Buy' link is clicked on `index.php`, on the `paynow.php` page does not show anything. Where have I gone wrong?

P.S: The`unitprice` echos fine. So I know that there is no issue is pulling data from the SQL database.

**index.php**

```
$sql_content = "show columns from cameras";
$get_res = mysql_query($sql_content);
$cols = mysql_num_rows($get_res);
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
$start = ($page-1)*8;
$sql_content1 = "select * from cameras limit $start,$per_page";
$query = mysql_query($sql_content1);

$j=0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
?>
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id='mainFrame'>
    <div id='totalFrame'>
        <div id='priceX'><b>Rs.&nbsp;</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['unitprice'];?></div><!--pricex-->
        <div id='buynow'><a href="paynow.php?id="<?php echo $rows['model']; ?>">Buy</a></div>
    </div><!--close total frame-->
</div>
<?php
```

**paynow.php**

```
<?php
print $_GET["id"]; 
?>
```

Comment: do `var_dump($rows)` and tell what what you see

Comment: When you click on the "Buy" link, what is the full URL that you get sent to?

Comment: Put: `<?php echo $rows['model']; die; ?>` right beneath `while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))` and tell us what it prints out.

Comment: @Will I noticed that too. Id is blank.. here's what it looks like. "http://localhost/bro/Products/paynow.php?id="

Comment: An HTML id has to be unique within a document. And why are you putting your style sheet link into the lop …?

Comment: @CBroe the idea is to create a different link for every row.

Comment: What does that have to do with inserting the same stylesheet multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you should immediately stop using any mysql_* functions. Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

The interface is now deprecated and you should use PDO_MySQL or MySQLi.

You also have a potential SQL injection vulnerability in your code as you're not sanitising the input to the SQL query.

For your question, the syntax highlighting right here on SO has highlighted your problem, you have an extra `"` in your code:

```
<div id='buynow'><a href="paynow.php?id="<?php echo $rows['model']; ?>">Buy</a></div>
```

Should be this:

```
<div id='buynow'><a href="paynow.php?id=<?php echo $rows['model']; ?>">Buy</a></div>
```

Comment: @DinukaWijesena You could always accept the answer if it helped :-)

Comment: i was waiting till the time passes :-)

Answer (score 0):

remove double-quotes `"` before `<?php:`

`<div id='buynow'><a href="paynow.php?id=<?php echo $rows['model']; ?>">Buy</a></div>`

Comment: How is that going to help?

Comment: trust me, i'm a programmer

Comment: I see the one you mean, the one after `id=`

Comment: your answer was useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
      echo htmlspecialchar($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
} else {
      echo "You must specify an ID!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `double quotes "`

```
<div id='buynow'><a href="paynow.php?id=<?=$rows['model']; ?>">Buy</a></div>
```